# Updating Apple Watch Complication by fetching data using a URL request

Tags: watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit, watchos-5

I am having a complication that needs to update once in a while by fetching data from a server.

I am trying to fetch the data from the Watch. I am doing so by scheduling a `WKRefreshBackgroundTask`. When this task fires, I start a URL session to fetch some JSON data from a server.

After the data has been fetched successfully, I complete the `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` by calling its `setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)`.

This all seems to work OK-ish, however, I'd rather create a `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` after the `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` to download it in the background and consume less time in the background tasks. I think this is not possible, I am not downloading or uploading files. If I understand correctly `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` with a `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:)` can only be used a   for `URLSessionUploadTask`s or `URLSessionDownloadTask`s, so I had to forget about that idea. (Please correct me if I misunderstood that).

Now the biggest problem I run into is that when the Watch is locked (taken off the wrist, put on the charging puck, etc.) the URL Requests are not being executed. And thus the data is not been updated. How should we deal with this? The activity compilation simply turns dark when the Watch gets locked and as soon as you unlock the Watch it reloads. Is there anything we can do to understand the Watch is locked/unlocked?

Is it even the right approach to fetch the data from the Watch using a `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask`, or is it better to wake up the phone and get the phone to request the data using `WatchConnectivity`? And if so: which `WCSessionDelegate` functions would you use to achieve that?

If fetching the data directly from the Watch is the way to go: can I set the `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` to completed before the request has completed, or should I wait until after the request completed? (i.e., at what point in time should `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot()` be called).

I read loads and loads of articles and watched multiple videos. Yet still I find it very hard to find what the correct architecture is to fetch compilation data from a server and get this working rock solid.

Hopefully someone can shine a little light on this matter.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? There are  lot of questions around WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask without any solutions.